# What is the correct way to add and analyse covariates in a 2x3 Mixed ANOVA in SPSS

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, spss, psychology

I am trying to analyze whether different intervention groups scored differently in questionnaire measures before and after an intervention.

The first independent variable is time at 2 levels (pre-intervention and post-intervention). The second independent variable is Intervention group at 3 levels.

I also want to include age and gender as covariates in order to control for them. Gender and age have both been included as a numeric variable type within SPSS as when i tried to code gender as a string variable type (e.g. M=1, F=2) it would not let me analyse the data.

I try to use a general linear model --> Repeated measures and then classify my within subjects factor as the scores on the two questionnaires at 2 levels. The intervention is put in as the Between-subjects factor and the gender and age are included as covariates.

The problems I am having:

1. Have I encoded gender into SPSS correctly for this kind of analysis?
2. Am I doing the correct kind of analysis for what I am trying to achieve?
3. Without including the covariates, there is a significant difference between pre-intervention and post-intervention (no significant interaction with the groups) however when including the covariates, intervention * gender is now only significant but the intervention is no longer significant. What does this mean?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use a repeated measures ANOVA, I would recommend conducting an ANCOVA, as advocated by [Vickers & Altman (2001)](https://www.bmj.com/content/bmj/323/7321/1123.full.pdf). This analysis adjusts the changes from baseline to follow-up for the baseline measurements. Specifically, this is a multiple regression with the follow-up measurements as dependent and the baseline measurements, dummy variables for the groups and other variables you want to adjust for as independent variables.

Here is a simulated dataset in SPSS. The data have to be in the wide-format, as shown here:

[image: Sample data]

*ID* is an identifier for each subject, *group* indicates the group, *sex* indicates the gender and *t1* and *t2* are the measurements at baseline and follow-up.

We can visualize the data using boxplots:

[image: Boxplots of the data]

The analysis itself is simple. Using the menu, go **Analyze $\rightarrow$ General Linear Model $\rightarrow$ Univariate**. I find it much easier to use the syntax directly. For this example, the syntax could look like this:

```
UNIANOVA t2 BY group sex WITH t1
  /METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
  /INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
  /SAVE=PRED ZRESID
  /EMMEANS=TABLES(group) WITH(t1=MEAN) COMPARE ADJ(BONFERRONI)
  /PRINT PARAMETER
  /CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
  /DESIGN=t1 group sex group.
```

The results are as follows:

[image: Model Output1]

We can see that there is evidence that the baseline value *t1* has an influence on the follow-up measurements (this is often not of interest). The line called *group* provides evidence that the change from baseline to follow-up differ between the groups. On the other hand, there is little evidence for a difference among genders with respect to change.

Next, we can compare the groups pairwise:

[image: Pairwise group comparisons]

These comparisons were corrected using Bonferroni adjustments. We can see that there is evidence that groups 1 vs. 2 and 2 vs. 3 differ with respect to their changes from baseline to follow up. Specifically, group 2 changed 5.65 points more on average compared to group 1. Group 3 changed 6.5 points less compared to group 2. (Note that these comparisons are calculated at the *mean* of the baseline measurements.)

This analysis can be expanded by including interaction terms or adding more covariates. One could, for example, include an interaction term of *sex* with *group,* allowing to test whether the change in each group depends on the gender.

Don't forget to perform model diagnostics as applicable to all (multiple) linear regression models: The syntax above saves the predicted values and the standardized residuals. These can subsequently be used to create a scatterplot of predicted values vs. residuals (Tukey-Anscombe plot) or a Q-Q-plot of the residuals.

Comment: Thank you very much for the well thought out and detailed reply. I appreciate it very much! Would you be able to expand on how to enter the different variables as a univariate test?

Comment: @Nick I don't fully understand what you mean by "enter the different variables as a univariate test". What do you want to test exactly?